# Searching for a query-able nationwide data source of official german TK25 cartography numbers

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, germany, federal

I am looking for a single data source containing the so-called [TK25](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messtischblatt) numbers, aka "Messtischblattnummern" (preferrably quarter-TK25).

I want to intersect the TK25 data with vector data (e.g., a polygon of an area) and subsequently query another data source with the resulting TK25 numbers for their database content.

I assumed a TK25 grid is out there, on an national level, but I could only find published data on state level.